# AutoMapper Stops Working After Period Of Time - Missing Type Map / Unsupported Mapping

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I have found very odd behavior. I have a service using AutoMapper and EF. This worked fine until I upgraded from .NET 4.0 to 4.5 and AutoMapper 3.2.1 (I realise there is a later version and I am looking at upgrading again in the future but stuck due to other dependencies).

The mappings are all correct, we have profiles that extend from Automapper.Profile and get called once to create the mappings.

The service works for a number of hours. Then it stops and I get the "Missing type map configuration / unsupported mapping" exceptions.

If I recycle the app pool (and also IIS as a whole) the issue persists. However, if I re-release (overwrite the service libraries, with the exact same ones), the service starts working again.

I have tried catching the exception but it gives me nothing.

```
class PersonProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        var map = Mapper.CreateMap<PersonType, PersonDto>();
        var mapback = Mapper.CreateMap<PersonDto, PersonType>();           
    }
}
```

Example mapping, which does work at first.

It seems odd that

1. It works initially then after time (either requests or time), it stops working
2. As the profile is only loaded once, why it would stop working in the first place
3. This seems to happen to all entities. If I remove the AutoMapping calls from some entities it will just happen to other entities later on in the process, as though its not down to the actual objects, but rather AutoMapper as whole thats failing.

I can only thing its a mixture of AutoMapper with EntityFramework and maybe IoC which is old (Castle Windsor). I am in the process of updating everything small bits at a time.

Comment: Interesting. Perhaps related to this: I initialize my maps in global.cs, Application_Start, as they say we should do (https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started#where-do-i-configure-automapper), but I noticed it simply was acting, actually immediately, not later on as in your case, as if I hadn't ever called it, getting the same exceptions you are getting (AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping). In debugging though, by simply calling the initialize map logic later within code (just once), it suddenly works. BUG!